# Meaning 「～と思う」 at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles

Mostly on the news I always hear 「～と思う」 very often at the end of a sentence, so i started to wonder, Does it has other meaning besides of "I think"?

Comment: These probably should have been asked as separate questions.

Comment: Yes, could you please re-ask the と思う part separately?

Comment: I'll just re ask for を part, I understood と思う

Answer (score 5):

One could argue that 思う has meanings other than "to think", such as "feel" or "regard", but they all boil down to thinking and emotions. The reason you hear it so often actually isn't because it has separate meanings. You hear it a lot because it shows the speaker is uncertain or has quoted an opinion and is not necessarily a fact. This makes it great for the news, because it takes the accountability off of the speaker. This is used *very* often, even outside the news.